# Deadlock when using fork, exec and pipes in a parallel environment

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, deadlock

I am spawning a child process using fork and exec. Using two pipes to provide input and receive output from that process.

It works just fine most of the time but when I use something like openmp to test how it performs in concurrent environments it hangs in the `read` syscall, or `waitpid` sometimes.

When I `strace`ed the child process I found that it is also blocked on the `read` syscall. Which is weird because I only wait on reading in the parent process after I've provided all of my input and **closed** the write end of the pipe.

I tried to create an MVCE but it is sort of long. I don't know how to make it any shorter. I removed most of the error checking code for the sake of simplicity.

Note that there are no globals in my code. And I'm not trying to read/write from the same file descriptors in multiple threads.

I can't think of what could go wrong. So hopefully you guys can spot what I'm doing wrong.

There goes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t
min(size_t first, size_t second)
{
    if(first < second)
    {
        return first;
    }

    return second;
}

struct RDI_Buffer
{
    char* data;
    size_t size;
};

typedef struct RDI_Buffer RDI_Buffer;

RDI_Buffer
rdi_buffer_init()
{
    RDI_Buffer b = {0};
    return b;
}

RDI_Buffer
rdi_buffer_new(size_t size)
{
    RDI_Buffer b;

    b.data = malloc(size);
    b.size = size;
    return b;
}

void
rdi_buffer_free(RDI_Buffer b)
{
    if(!b.data)
    {
        return;
    }

    free(b.data);
}

RDI_Buffer
rdi_buffer_resize(RDI_Buffer b, size_t new_size)
{
    if(!b.data)
    {
        return rdi_buffer_new(new_size);
    }

    char* new_data = realloc(b.data, new_size);

    if(new_data)
    {
        b.size = new_size;
        b.data = new_data;
        return b;
    }

    RDI_Buffer output = rdi_buffer_new(new_size);
    memcpy(output.data, b.data, output.size);
    rdi_buffer_free(b);
    return output;
}

RDI_Buffer
rdi_buffer_null_terminate(RDI_Buffer b)
{
    b = rdi_buffer_resize(b, b.size + 1);
    b.data[b.size - 1] = '\0';
    return b;
}

static RDI_Buffer
rw_from_fd(int w_fd, int r_fd, RDI_Buffer input)
{
    const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;

    assert(input.size <= CHUNK_SIZE);

    write(w_fd, input.data, input.size);
    close(w_fd);

    RDI_Buffer output = rdi_buffer_new(CHUNK_SIZE);

    read(r_fd, output.data, CHUNK_SIZE);

    close(r_fd);
    return output;
}

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        char* thing =
                "Hello this is a sort of long text so that we can test how "
                "well this works. It should go with cat and be printed.";

        RDI_Buffer input_buffer;
        input_buffer.data = thing;
        input_buffer.size = strlen(thing);

        int main_to_sub[2];
        int sub_to_main[2];

        pipe(main_to_sub);
        pipe(sub_to_main);

        int pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
            dup2(main_to_sub[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(sub_to_main[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

            close(main_to_sub[1]);
            close(main_to_sub[0]);
            close(sub_to_main[1]);
            close(sub_to_main[0]);

            char* argv[] = {"cat", NULL};

            execvp("cat", argv);
            exit(1);
        }

        close(main_to_sub[0]);
        close(sub_to_main[1]);

        RDI_Buffer output =
                rw_from_fd(main_to_sub[1], sub_to_main[0], input_buffer);

        int *status = NULL;
        waitpid(pid, status, 0);

        if(status)
        {
            printf("%d\n", *status);
        }

        output = rdi_buffer_null_terminate(output);

        if(strcmp(output.data, thing) == 0)
        {
            printf("good\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bad\n");
        }

        rdi_buffer_free(output);
    }
}
```

Make sure you compile and link with `-fopenmp`. Like so: `gcc main.c -fopenmp`

Comment: You don’t check for errors from your system calls. You should. You could be running out of file descriptors. With parallelism, 100 iterations of a loop that creates 4 file descriptors on each iteration could run into trouble if the limit is about 256 descriptors. Yes, you close some of them fast, but fast enough?  Not clear.  And indeterminacy of scheduling would easily account for the varying behaviour.

Comment: well I really simplified the program and removed error checking to reduce the line count and make it more readible.

Comment: The way I understand openmp is that it goes into the loop body n times at a time where n is the number of threads (am I wrong?). So at any single time I should never have more than n*2 file descriptors which on my machine should be around 24

Comment: It’s probably n*4 file descriptors, but there may be limits on the parallelism.  With forks and execs as well as threads, life gets tricky.  File descriptors may not be being closed that should be being closed because file descriptors are a process-level resource, so thread 1 may create file descriptors that thread 2 doesn’t know about, but which it does share.  And then the file descriptors aren’t closed, preventing the `cat` from detecting EOF properly, etc.

Comment: "*I can't think of what could go wrong*": without even looking at the code, my first thought is "multithreading and `fork` -- now there's a tricky combination."

Comment: All that passing around of structures by value seems a recipe for trouble, especially given that the structures contain pointers to dynamically allocated memory.  I don't think that's the cause of your problem, but it seems unwise.

Comment: I ran the posted code many times (on ubuntu linux 18.04) and it always executed successfully (resulting in a column of the text: `good`

Comment: In the future, if you remove error checking to follow the 'minimization' part of the guidelines for creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it is as well to say so in the question.  It is legitimate as long as your 'real' code assiduously checks all system calls (that can fail — system calls like `getpid()` can't fail) for failure.

Comment: Why do you ignore SIGPIPE in rw_from_fd()?   This should never happen, since you are controlling when cat exits.   It has side effects -- the first child (cat) you start has SIGPIPE enabled; the remainder inherit its ignored status from the parent.   I don't know if it is relevant, but __kmp_install_signals handles SIGPIPE as special...

Comment: How many cpus do you have available?

Comment: @mevets ignoring sigpipe is part of the original code. I should have removed it. In the original code I ignore sigpipes and handle the errors locally in the function with `errno()`

Comment: my machine has 12 cpus

Comment: @user3629249 Are  you sure you compile and link with `-fopenmp`?

Comment: I added the `-fopenmp` to my compile options.  It made no difference.  I'm compiling, as you suggested with `gcc` rather than `mpicc`

Comment: @Adam  when I moved to a 16cpu machine, it reproduces.  You aren’t crazy in at least one respect.   I find the children are all waiting on write....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your main is hung, type lsof in a separate session.   I think you will see something like:

```
....
cat       5323                 steve  txt       REG              252,0    52080    6553613 /bin/cat
cat       5323                 steve  mem       REG              252,0  1868984   17302005 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
cat       5323                 steve  mem       REG              252,0   162632   17301981 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
cat       5323                 steve  mem       REG              252,0  1668976   12849924 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
cat       5323                 steve    0r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32079 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    1w     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32080 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    2u      CHR              136,0      0t0          3 /dev/pts/0
cat       5323                 steve    3r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32889 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    4w     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32889 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    6r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32890 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    7r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      34359 pipe
cat       5323                 steve    8w     FIFO               0,10      0t0      32890 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   10r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      22504 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   15w     FIFO               0,10      0t0      22504 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   16r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      22505 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   31w     FIFO               0,10      0t0      22505 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   35r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      17257 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   47r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      31304 pipe
cat       5323                 steve   49r     FIFO               0,10      0t0      30264 pipe
```

which raises the question, where are all those pipes coming from?   Your main loop is no longer a single loop, it is a set of unsynchronized parallel loops.  Look at the boilerplate below:

```
void *tdispatch(void *p) {
      int to[2], from[2];
      pipe(to);
      pipe(from);
      if (fork() == 0) {
          ...
      } else {
          ...
          pthread_exit(0); 
     }
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < NCPU; i++) {
    pthread_create(..., tdispatch, ...);
}
for (int i = 0; i < NCPU; i++) {
    pthread_join(...);
}
```

Multiple instances of tdispatch can interleave the pipe(to), pipe(from), and fork() calls; thus fds are leaking into these fork'ed processes.   I say leaking because the forked'd process has no idea that they are there.

A pipe continues to respond to read() system calls while it either has buffered data or there is at least one write file descriptor open to it.

Suppose process 5 has its normal two ends of two pipes open, pointing to pipe#10, and pipe#11; and process 6 has pipe#12 and pipe#13.  But, owing to the leaking above, processes 5 also has the write end of pipe#12, and process 6 has the write end of pipe#10.   Process's 5 and 6 will never exit because they are keeping each others read-pipe's open.

The solution is pretty much what people in the earlier bit were saying: threads and forks are a tricky combination.   You would have to serialize your pipe,fork,initial-close bits in order to make it work.

Comment: Why would a child hang because it inherits an open pipe (that they will not read/write into)? Why wouldn't they just read/write to their stdin/stdout and then die leaving unclosed pipes for the kernel to handle?

Comment: I solved the issue btw by closing all file descriptors right after I fork. I just don't understand why was that a problem and why does my solution work.

Comment: I was not notified about your edit but I'm glad I refreshed the page :D Okay I finally understand now. EOF will not be sent, or the pipe will not be broken unless all the writing ends are closed ,whether it's from the main process or one of the children who inherited unknowingly. and since the children don't even know about these open files, they have no reason to close them and so the deadlock happens. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

You could be running out of file descriptors. With parallelism, 100 iterations of a loop that creates 4 file descriptors on each iteration could run into trouble if the limit is about 256 descriptors. Yes, you close some of them fast, but fast enough? That's not clear. And indeterminacy of scheduling would easily account for the varying behaviour.

> The way I understand openmp is that it goes into the loop body n times at a time where n is the number of threads (am I wrong?). So at any single time I should never have more than n*2 file descriptors which on my machine should be around 24.

It’s probably n*4 file descriptors, but there may be limits on the parallelism.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with OpenMP to comment authoritatively on that.  Are there pragmas other than the for loop one that should be set?  It isn't clear to me that running the code shown introduced parallelism on a Mac when the code is compiled with Clang — which doesn't complain about the `#pragma`, unlike GCC 9.1.0 which does warn about the unknown pragma under my default compilation options.

However, with forks and execs as well as threads, life gets tricky. File descriptors may not be being closed that should be being closed because file descriptors are a process-level resource, so thread 1 may create file descriptors that thread 2 doesn’t know about, but which it does share. And then when thread 2 forks, the file descriptors created by thread 1 aren’t closed, preventing the `cat` from detecting EOF properly, etc.

One way to verify this would be to use a function like this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

static void dump_descriptors(int max_fd)
{
    struct stat sb;
    for (int fd = 0; fd <= max_fd; fd++)
        putchar((fstat(fd, &sb) == 0) ? 'o' : '-');
    putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

and in the child code, call it with a suitable number (64 perhaps — there could be a case for using a number as large as 404).  Although it is tempting to try using `flockfile(stdout)` and `funlockfile(stdout)` in the function, it is pointless if it is only called in the child process because the child is single-threaded and therefore there won't be any interference from other threads in the process.  However, it is all too feasible that different processes might interfere with each other's output.

If you're going to use `dump_descriptor()` from the parent process threads, then add `flockfile(stdout);` before the loop and `funlockfile(stdout);` after the `fflush()` call.  I'm not sure how much that will interfere with the problem; it enforces single threading through that function because none of the other threads can write to `stdout` while one thread has it locked.

However, when I tested it with a slightly modified version of the code which output the PID before the 'good' and 'bad' lines, and before the `dump_descriptors()` output, I never saw any interleaving of operations.  I got output like:

```
14128: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14128: good
14129: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14129: good
14130: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14130: good
…
14225: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14225: good
14226: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14226: good
14227: ooooooo----------------------------------------------------------
14227: good
```

which strongly suggests there was no parallelism in the code.  And when there is no parallelism, you won't see the trouble.  Each time, there are 4 descriptors for the pipes, and the code carefully closes them.

Consider redirecting the descriptor map to a file (or one file per child) in your scenario, where you may actually be getting serious parallelism.

Note that mixing threads with `fork()` is inherently difficult (as [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328664/deadlock-when-using-fork-exec-and-pipes-in-a-parallel-environment?noredirect=1#comment99265623_56328664)) — you normally use one or the other mechanism, not both.

Comment: I think your GCC is complaining because you should provide -fopenmp as you compile/link

Comment: This code runs as part of a web server where each requests is a thread. Each request needs to spawn a child. So I am forced to use both multithreading and fork/exec. Maybe there is another way I don't know about?

Comment: @AdamZahran: Part of the problem was not compiling with `-fopenmp`; I find it surprising that the code did not have `#include <omp.h>` given that it is using OMP.  I'm not sure how much that matters.  On my Mac, I'm running into a undefined symbol `__emutls_get_address()`; this seems to be a known problem in some circumstances, but it is disappointing to find it afflicting GCC 9.1.0 when it was known back in the days of GCC 4.7 or thereabouts (4.x for a moderately large x).  And there's the env var `OMP_NUM_THREADS` which might be important too. This is stuff people who've used it know.

Comment: @AdamZahran: Did you find any evidence of unexpected open file descriptors?  I'm fairly sure that you would. You might need to think in terms of cycling through available file descriptors (at least up to some number such as 64) and simply closing them as you don't know what they're for but your child process doesn't need them. That's a pain, but if there isn't a central registry of file descriptors and their purposes, that may be what's required. You can do more work than simply printing `o` or `-`, of course; you might identify the file type, and perhaps whether it has a O_CLOEXEC set, etc.

Comment: I ended up doing that and it worked. I cycled through all open file descriptors and I closed them right after the fork. However I don't understand why does having open files cause the child to hang. I did dup2 the pipe files to the stdin/stdout, why does it care about any other open files? I wish I could understand how that works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue turns out to be the open files that are inherited to the child processes as Jonathan Leffler and Mevet explained in their answers. Please read their answers if you have that problem then refer back to my answer if you still do not understand or don't know what to do.

I will share my explanation in a way I would have understood right away. Also share my code solution to the issue.

Consider the following scenario:
Process A opens a pipe (which is two files).

Process A spawns Process B to communicate to it with the pipe. However it also creates Process C which inherits the pipe (the two files).

Now process B will continuously call `read(2)` on the pipe which is a blocking system call. (It will wait until someone writes to the pipe)

Process A finishes writing and closes their end of the pipe. Normally that would cause the `read(2)` syscall in Process B to fail and the program would exit (That's what we want).

However in our case since Process C does have an open write end of the pipe, the `read(2)` syscall in Process B will not fail and will block waiting for a write from the open write-end in Process C.

Things will be okay when Process C just ends.

The real deadlock would arrise in a different scenario where both B and C hold pipes for one another (As explained in Mevet's answer). Each one of them will be waiting for the other to close their ends of the pipes. Which will never happen causing the deadlock.

My solution was to close all open files I don't need right after the `fork(2)`

```
int pid = fork();

if(pid == 0)
{
    int exceptions[2] = {main_to_sub[0], sub_to_main[1]};
    close_all_descriptors(exceptions);
    dup2(main_to_sub[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(sub_to_main[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(main_to_sub[0]);
    close(sub_to_main[1]);

    char* argv[] = {"cat", NULL};

    execvp("cat", argv);
    exit(1);
}
```

Here's the implementation of `close_all_descriptors`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int
is_within(int fd, int arr[2])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if(fd == arr[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int
fd_is_valid(int fd)
{
    return fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) != -1 || errno != EBADF;
}

static void
close_all_descriptors(int exceptions[2])
{
    // getdtablesize returns the max number of files that can be open. It's 1024 on my system
    const int max_fd = getdtablesize();

    // starting at 3 because I don't want to close stdin/out/err
    // let dup2(2) do that
    for (int fd = 3; fd <= max_fd; fd++)
    {
        if(fd_is_valid(fd) && !is_within(fd, exceptions))
        {
            close(fd);
        }
    }
}
```